# php echo username of logged in user on profile page

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, echo

******I currently have a very basic but working system to allow people to sign up and then login to see their profile. However I am try to add 'Welcome "username"' to the profile page but I am having no luck with it.

This is the file login.php

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>1D Affection | Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="validate_login.php" >
        <table border="1" >
            <tr>
                <td><label for="email">Email</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" 
                  name="email" id="email"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="pass">Password</label></td>
                <td><input name="pass" 
                  type="password" id="pass"></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                <td><input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is validate_login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
// Grab User submitted information
$email = $_POST["email"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];

// Connect to the database
$con = mysql_connect("mysql.onedirectionaffection.co.uk","robjef2","********");
// Make sure we connected succesfully
if(! $con)
{
    die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
}

// Select the database to use
mysql_select_db("onedirectionaffection_members",$con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT email, pass FROM users WHERE email = $email");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($row["email"]==$email && $row["pass"]==$pass)
  header("Location: ../../profile/profile.php");
else
    echo"Sorry, your credentials are not valid, Please try again.";

  session_start();
$_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;
?>
```

and this is the current code for the profile page -

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>1D Affection</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" Type="text/css" href="../css/stylesheet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" Type="text/css" href="../css/font.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" Type="text/css" href="../css/profile.css" />
  </head>

  <body bgcolor="white">

    <div id="wrapperhead">
      <div id="headcont">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="../images/1DA logo ripped.png" height="150px">
        </div>

        <div class="subheading">
          <img src="../images/1d subheading.png" height="150px">
        </div>
      </div>


      </div> <!--END OF HEADER-->
    <div id="nav">




      <div class="navigation">

        <ul>

          <li><a class="nav" href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav" href="#">News</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav" href="#">Fan-fiction</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav" href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav" href="http://www.onedirectionstore.com/" target="_blank">Store</a></li>

        </ul>

      </div> <!-- END OF MENU-->
         <!-- END OF NAVIGATION-->
    </div>

      <div id="wrappercontent">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="maincont">
            <div class="profcust">


          <div class="profpic">

            </div>

            <div class="profinfo">

            </div>
            </div>

        <div class="username">
         Welcome 
            </div>

        <div class="story">

            </div>



          </div>
      <div class="sidenav">
        Coming Soon

          </div>


        </div><!--end of content-->

    </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

I dont know if it makes any difference but profile.php is in a separate subfolder.

I would like to add that I have only been studying php for a few hours so please forgive me if this is simple or if any answers dont make total sense to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: u didn't set any value to `$uname` then how can u set `$_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;`

Comment: Firstly, you already have sesion_start on the page so php will probably throw an error if you have it later on (just to let you know :)). Also, I take it the username is stored in the db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this line in your php

```
$_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;
```

But $uname is not defined anywhere.

Comment: so if I add 'Welcome <?php echo $uname; ?> into my profile.php file, should it work?

Comment: you are not assigned any value for `$uname` , so how can u echo the value ?

Comment: @RJCreatives if you have a valid value for uname assigned, yes, that's how you'd print it out. First it needs to be stored in the database sometime, and then after authentication,  needs to be retrieved from the database.